# learn python hard way exercise 50 This site cant be reached,localhost refused

Tags: python-2.7

I have been going through learn python hard way exercise 50,it is basically about building a small website,the complete problem statement available in below link
exercise-50 ( [https://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex50.html][1])

I have created the app.py file in the specified directory and compiled the app.py .This is my app.py file

```
import web

urls=('/','index')

app=web.application(urls,globals())

class index:
    def GET(self):
        greeting='hello world'
        return greeting

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run
```

When Iam trying to run this http://localhost:8080/ iam getting **This site cant be reached error localhost refused** to connect.I have switched off firewall as well.What is the solution for this?Do i need to install apache tomcat?Please help me out,what iam missing here.

Comment: Currently, this question is unanswerable. Please read [ask] and add a [mcve] to your question.

Comment: @Ben,I have edited details about what i did ,please help me getting this resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you just forgot the `()`at the end of your `app.run()` statement